# Linux How to check process scheduling policy & Priority?

Tags: linux

I want to check the scheduling policy & priorities of some threads without programming it.

Is there a way to get it from top or other command ?
In top, I can see the PR column (which is the priority) but How can I get the scheduling policy ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can find looking on

```
/proc/<your_pocess_id>/sched.
```

For example:

```
awk '/policy/ {print $NF}' /proc/8888/sched
```

that should return the policy for the process with id 8888

You also try with chrt -p 8888

Comment: I'm getting 0.
I read http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/can-someone-explain-the-output-of-proc-pid-sched-4175412750/ but didnt get the answer what 0 (or any other value) means ?

Comment: Look at man 7 sched, or http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html. If it's not clear you could use  chrt -p <YOUR_PID>

Answer (score 0):

Use ionice, more info with `man ionice`. For process with id 2914585:

```
# ionice -p2914585
best-effort: prio 2
```

For a `top`-like alternative: with `htop` you can add it as a column (F2, Columns).